# Why are my columns too wide when using only the grid module from Semantic UI?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, semantic-ui

I would like to use Semantic UI in my project and I have started with the grid system. At the moment I am only using the [pre-built grid module from GitHub](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/UI-Grid/).

The following HTML does not work as expected:

```
<div class="ui page grid">
  <div class="four wide column red">four</div>
  <div class="four wide column green">four</div>
  <div class="four wide column blue">four</div>
  <div class="four wide column yellow">four</div>
  <div class="sixteen wide column teal">sixteen</div>
</div>
```

This is the result I am getting:

[image: Columns too wide]

The columns are obviously too wide, four "four wide" columns don't fit and the sixteen wide column causes the scroll bar to appear.

It seems that these column divs are supposed to be box-sized which they are not. Their content widths add up exactly to the width of the page, however they also have 1rem padding which I believe is where the extra width comes from.

Is there a common Semantic UI css module that I need to include that adds some basic styles? I am only including grid.css from the above GitHub repository at the moment.

There are no other stylesheets being included and the container HTML page is otherwise blank.

**[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/j8okweLv/)**

Comment: Could you provide a Fiddle or a test page?

Comment: added a Fiddle link to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're only including the `grid.css` stylesheet. You still need the `semantic.css` stylesheet for the grid to work.

Here is the updated fiddle link, I only added the `semantic.min.css` resource to it, that fixed the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/DrkStrife/j8okweLv/1/

**EDIT:**

Looks like semantic does include everything. I checked the project and they are using a customized `reset.css` I have updated the fiddle and is still working.

http://jsfiddle.net/DrkStrife/j8okweLv/2/

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was something like that!

Comment: On a second though, this doesn't seem right -- semantic.css is a huge file that includes everything there is in Semantic UI (you can remove grid.css from the fiddle and it still works fine). I guess it still has to be custom-built to work properly for this use case. A pity, I thought I could just include the parts that I needed.

Comment: I downloaded their package and looked at their examples. There is one for Grid and they also include the `semantic.css` in it. As soon as I remove it, everything breaks. Looks like `semantic.css` is the core of the UI itself.

**EDIT** Here's the same file https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/master/examples/grid.html